# javascript array filter callback with thisArg not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, callback, arguments

According to the [The Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), the following is valid usage of filter with a callback AND an arg:
filter(callbackFn, thisArg)
Where 'thisArg' replaces the 'this' in the context of the callback.  However, this does not seem to be the case, or I can not get it to be the case.

In this simple example I should be able to filter the array based on the tags.  If I hard code a value inside the call back, it works but providing a tag via 'thisArg' nothing is returned and this.tag is undefined.

Thoughts?

```js
musics = [
  {
    name: 'stinks like unwashed adolescent',
    tags: ['teen', 'energetic', 'excelent']
  },
  {
    name: 'After beethovens 4th',
    tags: ['older', 'moving', 'excelent']
  },
  {
    name: 'wap',
    tags: ['hip-hop', 'pounding', 'excelent']
  }
]

const filterTags = (element, index, arr) => {
   console.log(this.tag)
   return element.tags.includes(this.tag)
}
console.log(musics.filter(filterTags, {tag:'teen'}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use an arrow function here since [arrow functions inherit their `this`-context from the enclosing scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Try this:

```js
const musics = [
  {
    name: 'stinks like unwashed adolescent',
    tags: ['teen', 'energetic', 'excelent']
  },
  {
    name: 'After beethovens 4th',
    tags: ['older', 'moving', 'excelent']
  },
  {
    name: 'wap',
    tags: ['hip-hop', 'pounding', 'excelent']
  }
]

const filterTags = function(element, index, arr) {
   console.log(this.tag)
   return element.tags.includes(this.tag)
}

console.log(musics.filter(filterTags, {tag:'teen'}))
```

A functional approach using a closure:

```js
const musics = [
  {
    name: 'stinks like unwashed adolescent',
    tags: ['teen', 'energetic', 'excelent']
  },
  {
    name: 'After beethovens 4th',
    tags: ['older', 'moving', 'excelent']
  },
  {
    name: 'wap',
    tags: ['hip-hop', 'pounding', 'excelent']
  }
]

const hasTag = tag => element => element.tags.includes(tag)

console.log(musics.filter(hasTag('teen')))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer